# Bash: How to capture output of subshell into variable and wait for it to finish?

Tags: bash

I am in the process of writing a bash script. In it, I call another script and capture its output into a variable:

```
OUTPUT=$(whatever --args 2>&1)
```

Sometimes the `whatever` command runs a bit longer, which means everything gets out of sync quickly for the rest of the script.

To give a bit more context: I am executing a script that backups some folders to an external HD and send the output of the backup script via email. In case the HD is not connected, the backup is retried until it succeeds. In these cases everything works fine, but as soon as I connect the HD, the email I receive is empty. I am pretty sure this is because the backup takes some time and the email is sent before it is finished.

How can I wait for the subshell to finish while still capturing the output into a variable?

I have read about `&` to return immediately and then just call `wait`, but I am really unsure about this since I don't quite understand yet for what `wait` will actually wait.

Comment: Your question is a little broad. It would help if you provide context explaining the *everything gets out of sync* part.

Comment: @Leon Sorry, I added a bit more context.

Comment: The single line of code you provided will wait until the command it contains has finished before continuing to the rest of the script, so this is not what your problem is.  Maybe your command actually finishes without writing any output, of something else is not working as you think it should.  You need to show more of your code.

Comment: *"How can I wait for the subshell to finish while still capturing the output into a variable?"* You don't have to do anything because it is how it always works (command substitution is performed after the command completes). The problem may be that your `whatever` command doesn't handle all possible error situations and in the described case exits prematurely.

Comment: There is also the possibility that your command launches a child process and does not wait for this child process to finish before returning.  I would not assume this is your problem, but is is theoretically possible.

Comment: Using `&` and calling `wait` immediately is almost equivalent to just not using `&`. Unless you want to do something between `&` and `wait`, such as a displaying progress bar, you can just forget about this idea.